# Emberjs: Best Practice Partials & Includes

Tags: angularjs, ember.js, partials, angularjs-ng-include

I am new to Ember, but I have extensive Angular experience.

I am trying to create a single page web application with ember.

My app will be pretty extensive and large, so I would like to separate the page into multiple views.

Every Ember demo and tutorial creates an application only using the index.html page.

In Angular, we have a view attribute (`ng-view`) and use includes with partials. (`ng-include`)

Does ember have an equivalent? If so, can you direct me to any documentation or demo that uses it?

PS - I know I can dynamically build an HTML file with `GRUNT` by taking smaller HTML files and concat/uglifying them together, but is that the best practice or does ember have a view and include system equivalent.

Comment: There are views (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html) and partials (http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-partial-code-helper) in EmberJS.

Comment: Are you asking about .hbs files and how do you connect them to a project? If yes, take a look for example how the build works at ember-cli. If you prefer Gulp, ember-rocks is a good option.